# Matching two dataframes by columns while preserving multiple matches

Tags: r, merge, left-join, coalesce

I have two datasets. One has the name of some ethnic groups (The "Branoo", "Sinatu" and Gulipo" and their political claims (Independence or Irredentism) by year:

```
 Groups <- data.frame(group_names = c("Barnoo", "Sinatu", "Gulipo"),
                 year = c("2000", "2000", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2002", "2002", "2002"),
                 claim = c("Independence", "Irredentism", "Irredentism", "Independence", "Irredentism", "Independence", "Independence", "NA", "Irredentism"))
```

[image]

A second dataset has yearly information on which states support each group's claim. One state can support multiple groups, and one group can be supported by multiple states:

```
Countries <- data.frame(group_names = c("Egypt", "Jordan", "Greece"),
                      year = c("2000", "2000", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2002", "2002", "2002"),
                      support_independence = c("Barnoo", "Sinatu", "NA", "Barnoo", "Sinatu", "NA", "NA", "Sinatu", "NA"),
                      support_independence2 = c("Sinatu", "NA", "NA", "Sinatu", "NA", "NA", "Sinatu", "NA", "NA"),
                      support_irredentism = c("NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "Barnoo")
```

[image]

My goal is to have a table that lists each ethnic group, its claim, and its supporting states like so:

| Group | Year | Supporter of Independence 1 | Supporter of Independence 2 | Supporter of Irredentism 1 | Supporter of Irredentism 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Branoo | 2000 | Egypt | NA | NA | NA |
| Branoo | 2001 | Egypt | NA | NA | NA |
| Sinatu | 2000 | Egypt | Jordan | NA | NA |
| Sinatu | 2001 | Egypt | Jordan | NA | NA |

I feel like this should be relatively simple, but I'm having trouble dealing with the fact that I can't just match groups to countries 1:1 because some groups have multiple supporting countries.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

A crude way with `tidyverse`:

```r
library(tidyverse)
left_join(Groups[1:2], Countries[1:3], by = c("year", "group_names" = "support_independence")) %>% 
  left_join(Countries[c(1, 2, 4)], by = c("year", "group_names" = "support_independence2")) %>% 
  left_join(Countries[c(1, 2, 5)], by = c("year", "group_names" = "support_irredentism")) %>% 
  set_names(colnames(Countries))
```

```r
  group_names year support_independence support_independence2 support_irredentism
1      Barnoo 2000                Egypt                  <NA>                <NA>
2      Sinatu 2000               Jordan                 Egypt                <NA>
3      Gulipo 2000                 <NA>                  <NA>                <NA>
4      Barnoo 2001                Egypt                  <NA>                <NA>
5      Sinatu 2001               Jordan                 Egypt                <NA>
6      Gulipo 2001                 <NA>                  <NA>                <NA>
7      Barnoo 2002                 <NA>                  <NA>              Greece
8      Sinatu 2002               Jordan                 Egypt                <NA>
9      Gulipo 2002                 <NA>                  <NA>                <NA>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful! I think a problem would arise if there are multiple countries supporting independence of one group in the same column. For example, both Jordan and Egypt could have "Barnoo" in their "support_independence" column

Comment: Like in this case: 

Countries <- data.frame(country_names = c("Egypt", "Jordan", "Greece"),
                      year = c("2000", "2000", "2000", "2001", "2001", "2001", "2002", "2002", "2002"),
                      support_independence = c("Barnoo", "Sinatu", "NA", "Barnoo", "Sinatu", "NA", "NA", "Barnoo", "NA"),
                      support_independence2 = c("Sinatu", "NA", "NA", "Sinatu", "NA", "NA", "Sinatu", "NA", "NA"))